# How to do scaling while using json in cocos2d-x ios game using c++

Tags: c++, json, cocos2d-x

I am using cocostudio and exporting a scene from it where it exports a .plist ,.png and a .json file.The scene is working fine in iphone retina 3.5 inch but the scaling is not perfect in ipad and iphone.How to we control scaling while using .json and importing a complete scene uin diffrent devices
in the init function I am writing

```
CCNode *pFishJoyScene = SceneReader::sharedSceneReader()->createNodeWithSceneFile("FishJoy2.json");
this->addChild(pFishJoyScene);             
cocos2d::extension::ActionManager::shareManager()->playActionByName("startMenu_1.json","Animation1");
```

Earlier I used to use CCSize winsize=CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getwinSize();.While using this I used to scale all the things.

But in case of json we dont need to write this as we are creating a scene in cocostudio.Please tell me how to control the scaling in different devices while using .json

I have taken sample examples from 
https://github.com/chukong/CocoStudioSamples

I run a project named in the above sample DemoFishingjoy.If you run this sample project in different devices it will lead to scaling problems.Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the answer is that whatever i take whether its a scene or anything i take it in a node.Just scale the node and everything will be perfect.For example

```
CCNode *pFishJoyScene = SceneReader::sharedSceneReader()->createNodeWithSceneFile("FishJoy2.json");
this->addChild(pFishJoyScene);
cocos2d::extension::ActionManager::shareManager()->playActionByName("startMenu_1.json","Animation1");

CCSprite *bg=CCSprite::create("startMenuBG.png");
float rX=winSize.width/bg->getContentSize().width;
float rY = winSize.height/bg->getContentSize().height;


pFishJoyScene->setScaleX(rX);
pFishJoyScene->setScaleY(rY);
```

Then you will see in any device that it works perfect

Answer (score 0):

```
I hope this will help you.for scaling in skeletonAnimation setScaleX() and setScaleY() are used 

      CCSkeletonAnimation* skeletonAnimRun = CCSkeletonAnimation::createWithFile("horse.json", "horse.atlas");
            skeletonAnimRun->setAnimation("run", true);
            skeletonAnimRun->timeScale = 1.0f;
            skeletonAnimRun->setScaleX(.2f);
            skeletonAnimRun->setScaleY(.2f);
            skeletonAnimRun->setPosition(x/5, y/2);
            skeletonAnimRun->setSkin("black");
            skeletonAnimRun->setSlotsToSetupPose();
            addChild(skeletonAnimRun,10);
```